# XCode iOS UISlider - Custom Scaling Min and Max

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

I want to have a different scale using a slider for the Min and Max. 0 should be in the middle, but I want to have a scale 0-50 for max and -200-0 for min.

Is that possible? How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this is possible out of the box.

But what you can do is, e.g. setup the slider in a way that for min it has 0 and for max 1000. Now you will have to check in which part of the part, user left the slider. If it's in the lower half, you will have to normalize  those values to the desired range, the same for the upper range. The exact middle could be a bit tricky because you will have more points in the slider than in the ranges you are providing, but I guess with some fiddling around you can do this. :)

Hope that helped  :)

Comment: Hello, correct answer. This worked very well for me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is quite possible.

Here is my idea of how you can do it

1. Take a slider with values -200 to 200
2. For values > 0. Divide value by 4. (i.e. 200 / 4 = 50)
3. This will make your positive range from 0 to 50 but negative range from -200 to 0

Similarly while setting value to slider in positive manner you can multiply it by 4.